# Android Studio v.2021.2.1 update failed

Tags: android-studio

When I try to update Android Studio on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS through the default interface (Help -> Check for updates), it finds the new version (2021.2.1 Patch 1), starts the download, restarts, and then shows the following window:

[image: Error updating Android Studio on Ubuntu 22.04.01]

I can't do anything at this dialogue except cancel, and when I press the "Cancel" button, Android Studio starts the old version (2021.2.1 without the patch). I can repeat this several times.

Maybe someone has some ideas?

Comment: Run out of disk space ?

Comment: @Marco Definitely not. 150+ Gb free

Answer (score 0):

So, since I could not find a normal solution for updating the version, I had to do it differently, since version 2021.2.1 simply began to constantly bombard me with errors.

I downloaded the latest version available from the Android Studio website (Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1) and unpacked it into a separate folder (because I wasn't sure if all the settings would transfer correctly otherwise). At startup, she offered to transfer the settings, with which I agreed. Everything worked correctly, she saw my project. After that, I deleted the old version, and simply rename the new folder the same as the old one. At the moment, everything is more or less acceptable. Hope this help anyone.